# Theorem on meromorphisms - complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

S is a sequence converging to $z_0$ and f is analytic is a disk centred at $z_0$ show either that f extends meromorphically on some neighbourhood of f(z) or else for any $L \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists a sequence $w_j$ such that $w_j \rightarrow z_0$ and $f(w_j) \rightarrow L$

I'm really stuck could someone give me a starting point. My initial thoughts are that $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-L}$ would be bounded in some neighbourhood of $z_0$ then apply Riemann's removable singularity theorem and for $z_0$ and show it extends meromorphically, the main trouble is the or else part.

Comment: I thought maybe applying the Cavort-Weierstrass theorem but not quite sure how to.

Comment: I've got it for essential and removable singularities, I think i only need to prove which is the case if there is a pole of order N at $z_0$

Comment: For a pole of order $N$ at $z_0$, you should show that it "extends meromorphically". This is almost by definition, once you sort things out, I think.